# Are mixed type indexes acceptable in Neo4j?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a data set which includes a number of nodes, all of which labeled `claim`, which can have various properties (names `P1`, `P2`, etc., through `P2000`). Currently, each of the `claim` nodes can have only one of these properties, and each property has value, which can be of different types (i.e. `P1` may be string, `P2` may be float, `P3` integer, etc.). I also need to be able to look up the nodes by any property (i.e. `"find all nodes with P3 which equals to 42"`).

I have modeled it as nodes having property `value` and label according to the P property. Then I define schema index on label `claim` and property `value`. The lookup then would look something like:

```
MATCH (n:P569:claim) WHERE n.value = 42 RETURN n
```

My first question is - is this OK to have such index? Are mixed type indexes allowed?

The second question is that the lookup above works (though I'm not sure whether it uses index or not), but this doesn't - note the label order is switched:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n:claim:P569) WHERE n.value>0 RETURN n; 
IncomparableValuesException: Don't know how to compare that. Left: "113" (String); Right: 0 (Long)
```

`P569` properties are all numeric, but there are string properties from other P-values one of which is "113". Somehow, even though I said the label should be both claim and P569, the "113" value is still included in the comparison, even though it has no P569 label:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n:claim) WHERE n.value ="113" RETURN LABELS(n);
+-------------------+
| LABELS(n)         |
+-------------------+
| ["claim","P1036"] |
| ["claim","P902"]  |
+-------------------+
```

What is wrong here - why it works with one label order but not another? Can this data model be improved?

Comment: you can also use toString() on properties or toInt() if you want to compare them. Indexes can have mixed-types. You can also add index hints with `USING INDEX n:claim(value)`. In an index the values are I think mostly stored in a comparable format (or as strings)

Answer (score 3):

Let me at least try to side-step your question, there's another way you could model this that would resolve at least some of your problems.

You're encoding the property name as a label.  Perhaps you want to do that to speed up looking up a subset of nodes where that property applies; still it seems like you're causing a lot of difficulty by shoe-horning incomparable data values all into the same property named "value".

What if, in addition to using these labels, each property was named the same as the value?   I.e.:

```
CREATE (n:P569:claim { P569: 42});
```

You still get your label lookups, but by segregating the property names, you can guarantee that the query planner will never accidentally compare incomparable values in the way it builds an execution plan.  Your query for this node would then be:

```
MATCH (n:P569:claim) WHERE n.P569 > 5 AND n.P569 < 40 RETURN n;
```

Note that if you know the right label to use, then you're guaranteed to know the right property name to use.  By using properties of different names, if you're logging your data in such a way that P569's are always integers, you can't end up with that incomparable situation you have.  (I think that's happening because of the particular way cypher is executing that query)

A possible downside here is that if you have to index all of those properties, it could be a lot of indexes, but still might be something to consider.

Comment: As I understand, naming the properties differently would require maintaining 2000 indexes, and my experiments show trying to create 2000 indexes makes Neo4j grind to a halt and crash with OOM errors.

Comment: What are your data volumes?  Do you need indexes on all 2000?  Mixing data types in a single property as you are, it seems like unless you plan your queries very carefully, comparing incomparable values may frequently come up.  And in some ways, it's a misuse of that single attribute, since you're putting 2,000 different kinds of information into one attribute.

Comment: Full data volume is in the order of ~100M items. Yes, all properties need to be indexed.

Comment: I tried to create separate indexes for all 2000 properties and I get too many open files within Lucene, even when increasing file limit to 100k. Looks like there's a limit on how many indexes you can have.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be creating a lucene index on a property that you know is always going to be an integer.   Consider doing it this way:  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-create-index-on-a-label   -- lucene "legacy indexes" are best when you need text search, but probably not numeric range search, etc.

Comment: so which index should I use? I'm using schema indexes now, just like you linked to.

Comment: You should post more code and open a second question about "too many indexes".   you're saying you're getting "too many open files" with lucene, and yet if you're indexing according to those docs, I don't see how that's possible as those indexes aren't implemented with lucene (AFAIK).   I imagine somewhere you're probably programattically creating 2K indexes with java code, but the indexes I'm talking about would be done via cypher.   Look I think 2K indexes is probably excessive, but you're getting a separate error that should be investigated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to take a step back and think what you actually want to achieve, and why you have those 2000 properties in the first place and how you could model them differently in a graph?

Also make sure to just leave off properties you don't need and use `coalesce()` to provide the default.

Comment: I have 2000 properties because data items can have 2000 different properties. I'm open to ideas on how to represent them best in the graph.